# How can I draw those arrows to describe the composition of two functions?

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

I want to draw something like this with LaTeX. I know how to draw the two straight arrows, but how can I make the bottom shaped arrow?

[image]

Comment: I was going to suggest using `dot` as an alternative, but sometimes `dot` has problems with where to put labels on edges.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something likes this. In particular, the anlge 30 can be changed to suit one's need.

```
\draw[->,>=stealth] (a) edge[bend right=zz]node[below]{C} (c);
\draw[->,>=stealth] (a) edge[out=xx, in=yy]node[below]{C} (c);
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) (a) {a};
\node[right =1cm of a]  (b){b};
\node[right =1cm of b]  (c){c};
\draw[->,>=stealth] (a) --node[above]{A} (b);
\draw[->,>=stealth] (b) --node[above]{B} (c);
\draw[->,>=stealth] (a) edge[bend right=30]node[below]{C} (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Any idea how to do something like this in Mathjax?

Answer (score 11):

Using the powerful [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) is a one-liner:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
a\ar[r,"A"]\ar[rr,out=-30,in=210,swap,"C"] & b\ar[r,"B"] & c
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option, with the `graphs` and `quotes` libraries from TikZ as suggested by [Henri Menke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175379/how-can-i-draw-those-arrows-to-describe-the-composition-of-two-functions/175384?noredirect=1#comment405796_175384):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,quotes}

\begin{document}

\tikz \graph[multi] {a->["A"] b ->["B"] c; a->[bend right,"C" below] c; };

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also a very nice way to do. It is especially saving key strokes.

Comment: @magu_ Besides saving key strokes, `tikz-cd` was specifically designed for easily drawing commutative diagrams.

Comment: Can this also be done using the `graph` library?

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, it can be done. I added an example to my answer (I cannot upload images right now). Thnaks for the suggestion.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you! I added the picture for you in return.

Answer (score 5):

Run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\psset{shortput=nab,arrows=->,nodesep=2pt}
\begin{document}

\Rnode{a}{a}\qquad\Rnode{b}{b}\qquad\Rnode{c}{c}
\ncline{a}{b}^{A}\ncline{b}{c}^{B}
\nccurve[angleA=-45,angleB=225]{a}{c}_{C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A MetaPost solution, making use of the *boxes* package. More verbose, obviously, than the *tikz* and *pstricks* solutions, but efficient all the same. To be run with LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibsetformat{metafun}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
  input boxes;
  u := 2cm;
  beginfig(1);
    boxjoin(a.e + (u, 0) = b.w;);
    boxit.a("$a$"); drawunboxed(a);
    boxit.b("$b$"); drawunboxed(b);
    boxit.c("$c$"); drawunboxed(c);
    path ab, bc, ac; 
    ab = a.e -- b.w; drawarrow ab; label.top("$A$", point 0.5 of ab);
    bc = b.e -- c.w; drawarrow bc; label.top("$B$", point 0.5 of bc);
    ac = a.se .. c.sw{dir 30}; drawarrow ac; label.bot("$C$", point 0.5 of ac);
    setbounds currentpicture to boundingbox currentpicture enlarged 3bp;
  endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]